# AOP Pointcut expression on a bean having a lookup method

Tags: java, spring, proxy, spring-aop, spring-bean

I have a spring bean -> lookupMethodBean (singleton) having a look-up method to inject a prototype bean. I have now specified a pointcut expression to capture the method execution time of the lookupMethodBean. There is another bean -> impactedBean which passes lookupMethodBean as a constructor argument.

On startup, the bean initialization (impactedBean) fails with the following error:

'org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable#3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'impactedBean' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'impactedBean' defined in class path resource [beanDefinitions.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.xyz.LookupMethodBeanClass]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94] to required type [com.xyz.LookupMethodBeanClass]: Failed to convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94 implementing net.sf.cglib.proxy.Factory,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.xyz.LookupMethodBeanClass'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94 implementing net.sf.cglib.proxy.Factory,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.xyz.LookupMethodBeanClass]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)

The bean definitions are as follows:

```
<bean id="lookupMethodBean" class="com.xyz.LookupMethodBeanClass">
    <lookup-method name="lookupPrototype" bean="prototypeBean" />
</bean>
<bean id="impactedBean" class="com.xyz.ImpactedBeanClass">  
    <constructor-arg index ="0" ref="lookupMethodBean"/>
</bean>
```

The pointcut expression is as follows: 
`execution(* com.xyz.LookupMethodBeanClass.execute(..))`

If I update the pointcut expression to point to some other class, the application context gets initialized correctly. Since LookupMethodBeanClass is a concrete class and not having any interface, a CGLib proxy is getting created to handle the lookup logic. As for the AOP pointcut expression, it seems that a JDK proxy is getting created and both of them don't seem to gel together and results in this issue.

Please advise as to how to get around this issue.